# How do you get value of item tag in scriban template

Tags: sxa, scriban

Sorry this is probably a dumb question but I am a bit stuck in here and I can't find suitable solutions in google. Basically I have an item or a page with a Tagging on it.
But I can't seem to get the value of tags using scriban template.

I tried using

```
{{i_item.tags}}
```

and

```
{{sc_raw i_item 'Tags'}}
```

and

```
      {{ for i_child in i_item.sxa_tags }}
        <span>{{ i_child.Title }}</span>
      {{ end }}
```

Anyhelp will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Sample](https://gist.github.com/michaellwest/87fedb002a104387438177faa325bcbc)

Here is an example of how I used tags for listing departments associated with media items.

```
{{ if i_item.SxaTags != "" }}
<span>
Department: 
</span>
{{ tags = [] }}
{{ for i_tag in (sc_followmany i_item "SxaTags") }}
{{ tags[tags.size] = i_tag | sc_field "Title" }}
{{ end }}
{{ tags | array.sort | array.join ", " }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: THANK YOUUU You save me hours mate! Cheers

Comment: Thinking about it, I don't think it's convention to use the `$` character in variables. Updated to reflect that.